# Download a login page and its subfolders

Tags: download, login

I want to download a specific page and its subfolders/subpages, which could for instance be the primary page https://example.com/pageaboutlitterature/ and then something like subpages/subfolders that looks like this: https://example.com/pageaboutlitterature/writers...

The problem is that I use a login to acces the page. I tried downloading it with HTTRACK and filled out "Authentication", but it still only downloaded the site as it is when you are logged out. 
You can see what I mean here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09xTU.png)

Anybody who has suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Give [this one](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-configure-httrack-for-a-website-with-password-protection) a shot. It worked for me long back. I guess you are making some mistake while HTTrack authetication capture process. Be sure to follow the instruction and set correct proxy.

Comment: I got to the step where I have to capture the URL. However, it won't work since the site is only accesible through https and as I see HTTRACK only allows me to capture the URL of sites with http solely.